# How to center my main navigation bar on my site with css?

Tags: css, center

My site is: [Keto.hu](http://keto.hu), and I tried everything, but i can't center the navigation bar for wider screens.
I'd also like to center the recipe grid, if it's possible with css?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: your site crashed my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `#main-nav` set to `display:inline-block`, `margin:0 auto;` won't work.  Instead, you can set `header`'s `text-align` to `center`:

```
header {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible, to center #grid too with css?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your header.

```
text-align: center;
```

Like so:

```
header {
    text-align: center;
}
```